# Where is the Xpad content stored on disk?

Tags: logs

I had installed the Xpad package on Ubuntu 13.10 and had taken a few notes in it. I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and have taken the backup of the entire home folder. At which location is the content of the Xpad stored on the disk? If it is somewhere in the home folder, maybe I could retrieve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your notes are saved in `~/.config/xpad` folder.

Open up nautilus (files) and head to that folder,
your notes are in files named `content-******` where * are unique random characters.

Opening one in a text editor will display your notes for that pad.

See screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Xpad stores its notes on `~/.config/xpad`.

Answer (score 3):

After restoring your Home folder, open a new Note. Now, right click on the new Note, then click on *Notes* > *Show All*. It should retrieve all of your Notes.

Comment: Awesome. worked for me